# How to properly encode binary data to send over REST api PUT call

Tags: c#, rest, azure, http, put

I'm trying to simply upload an image file to Azure blob store and the file is making it there but the file size is bigger than it should be and when I download the file via the browser it won't open as an image.

I manually uploaded the same file via the Azure interface and the file works and is 22k, uploading via my code is 29k and doesn't work.

**NOTE:** One thing to note is that all the examples used with this code only send text files. Maybe the Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody); line is doing it?

This is where I'm Base64 encoding my data

```
HttpPostedFileBase hpf = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFileBase
byte[] binData;
using (BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(hpf.InputStream))
    binData = b.ReadBytes(hpf.ContentLength);

var result = System.Convert.ToBase64String(binData);
new BlobHelper("STORENAMEHERE", "SECRETKEY").PutBlob("images", "test.jpg", result);
```

This is what I'm using to PUT the data, it's from https://azurestoragesamples.codeplex.com/

```
public bool PutBlob(string container, string blob, string content)
{
    return Retry<bool>(delegate()
    {
        HttpWebResponse response;

        try
        {
            SortedList<string, string> headers = new SortedList<string, string>();
            headers.Add("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");

            response = CreateRESTRequest("PUT", container + "/" + blob, content, headers).GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            response.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError &&
                ex.Response != null &&
                (int)(ex.Response as HttpWebResponse).StatusCode == 409)
                return false;

            throw;
        }
    });
}

public HttpWebRequest CreateRESTRequest(string method, string resource, string requestBody = null, SortedList<string, string> headers = null,
    string ifMatch = "", string md5 = "")
{
    byte[] byteArray = null;
    DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    string uri = Endpoint + resource;

    HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = method;
    request.ContentLength = 0;
    request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", now.ToString("R", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2009-09-19");

    if (headers != null)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> header in headers)
            request.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(requestBody))
    {
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");

        byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody);
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    }

    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", AuthorizationHeader(method, now, request, ifMatch, md5));

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(requestBody))
        request.GetRequestStream().Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

    return request;
}
```

Comment: Guess it's not related to the size, but rather to the headers in your request. Could you add the code which calls `CreateRESTRequest()`?

Comment: @vorou OP updated

Comment: The size increase from 22k to 29k is roughly 3:4, so it looks like you are Base64-encoding twice somewhere.

Comment: @user6060561 it's encoding it with UTF8 in the CreateRESTRequest method after I've already Base64 encoded it. Might be it but I need to convert my binary to string even before I call that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is with how you're converting the binary data to string and then converting it back to byte array.

While converting binary data to string, you're using `System.Convert.ToBase64String` however while getting the byte array from string you're using `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes`. Most likely this is causing the mismatch.

Please change the following line of code:

```
byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody);
```

to

```
byteArray = System.Convert.FromBase64String(requestBody);
```

and that should fix the problem.

Comment: I was actually able to get this working by removing both UTF encoding and the Base64 encoding. The examples provided were hard-coded to only work with text files apparently. Although I thought you had to encode it someway before sending over http